# Ruby on Rails Video Upload Via Carrier Upload not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, html5-video

I'm trying to upload and display this video on my application built on Ruby on Rails. I am using the carrierwave gem to do this. I believe I have the file upload part working however when I go to my show method, no video is shown. The video is meant to be attached to a model called "post". I'm not fully sure how video tags work in Ruby.

The video tag exists in this file.

**show.html.erb**

```
<h1>Videos </h1>
<% @posts.each do |post|%>
<%= video_tag post.video_url.to_s%>
<%end%>
```

**posts_controller.rb**

```
def index
  @posts = Post.all
end


def show
  @posts=Post.all
end


def new
  @post = Post.new
end


 def create
  @post = Post.new(post_params)
  if @post.save
    flash[:success] = "The video was added!"
    redirect_to @post
  else
    render 'new'
  end
end

  private
  def post_params
      params.require(:post).permit(:video)
  end           
end
```

**post.rb**

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
      mount_uploader :video, VideoUploader  
end
```

**add_video_to_post.rb**

```
 class AddVideoToPost < ActiveRecord::Migration
    def change
    add_column :posts, :video, :string
    end
 end
```

**_form.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for(@post) do |f| %>
 <% if @post.errors.any? %>
 <div id="error_explanation">
   <h2><%= pluralize(@post.errors.count, "error") %></h2>

  <ul>
  <% @post.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
    <li><%= message %></li>
  <% end %>
  </ul>
  </div>
<% end %>

<div class="actions">
  <%=f.file_field :video%>
<%= f.submit %>
</div>
```

I believe it is something wrong with the video tag in my show page. The original tutorial that I followed said the video tag should be this:

```
<%= video_tag post.video_url.to_s :controls =>true %>
```

However, this gives me the error:

```
wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)
```

Can anyone help out?

Comment: Have you tried to put coma before `:controls` in video tag arguments?

Comment: Thanks. Adding a comma shows a video player with nothing in it. I can press the play button and it says that the video length is 0:00 seconds. There is a download button as well and clicking it downloads the correct video. However, the video player does not show anything other then a play and pause button and a progress bar with 0:00 seconds.

Comment: are you sure that the video is in format supported by your browser?

Comment: Thank you! The video format was not supported, uploading another video format fixed the problem.